# Редактирование списка в Python

Tags: python, list

Задача: Посчитать кол-во единиц в каждом элементе списка и если их больше или равно 2, то заменить этот элемент на "YES", в противном случае - "NO".

Код, который я имею на данный момент:

```
# Кол - во элементов списка
number = int(input())

# Список элементов
tasks = []
for element in range(number):
    # Вручную вводим элементы
    tasks.append(input())

# Промежуточный список для работы с элементами списка tasks
result = []
for x in range(0, len(tasks) - 1):
    # Делим каждый элемент списка tasks на подэлементы
    # и записываем в список result
    result = tasks[x].split()
    # Проходим по каждому элементу списка result 
    for y in range(0, len(result) - 1):
        # Проверка, если в элементе списка result больше или равно 2 единиц
        if result.count('1') >= 2:
            tasks[x] = "YES"
            result.clear()
        else:
            tasks[x] = "NO"
            result.clear()

print(tasks)
```

Проблема в том, что 1 - ый элемент списка tasks у меня заменяется на строку "YES", а все последующие элементы - нет.

Входные данные:

```
2 
1 0 1
0 0 1
```

Выходные данные:

```
['YES', 'NO']
```

UPD:
Проблема решена. Теперь все элементы в исходном списке заменяются на 'YES', 'NO в зависимости от кол - ва единиц в элементе.
Исправленный код:

```
# Кол - во элементов списка
number = int(input())

# Список элементов
tasks = []
for element in range(number):
    # Вручную вводим элементы
    tasks.append(input())

# Промежуточный список для работы с элементами списка tasks
result = []
for x in range(0, len(tasks)):
    # Делим каждый элемент списка tasks на подэлементы
    # и записываем в список result
    result = tasks[x].split()
    # Проверка, если в элементе списка result больше или равно 2 единиц
    if result.count('1') >= 2:
        tasks[x] = "YES"
        result.clear()
    else:
        tasks[x] = "NO"
        result.clear()
```

P.S Убрал второй цикл, т.к он оказался не нужен.
Цикл `for x in range(0, len(tasks)) - 1` заменил на `for x in range(0, len(tasks))`.

Comment: А еще стоит обратить внимание на поведение [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range). Единицу от длины списка отнимать нельзя в данном случае.

Comment: Во-первых с вашими данными выходной результат совершенно правильный. Во-вторых непонятно, зачем вам вообще второй цикл - вы не используете переменную `y` вообще

Answer (score 5):

```
['YES' if i.count('1') >= 2 else 'NO' for i in tasks]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Этот вариант тоже подходит